# JQUERY UI Dialog dragging is extremely slow in IE 10 but fast in chrome

Tags: jquery

I've been scratching my head about this script for about 2 days now, and this is extremely slow in IE 10, but works smoothly and fast with chrome. Is there any code optimization for jqueryui dialog with draggable option is enabled that is fast in IE 10? Below is my code. Thanks.

```
$("#AppendGrid_Div").dialog({
    height: "420px",
    width: "auto",
    dialogClass: 's-dialog',
    position: {
        of: $("#container"),
        my: "left bottom",
        at: "left bottom"
    },
    open: function () {
        $("#AppendGrid_Div").appendTo($("#AppendGrid_Div"));
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't worry, no one uses IE10 :P

Comment: It's the worst I've got from my client requirements. Hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Animations in jquery are rendered by JavaScript engines, which can be either fast or slow depending upon the browsers.

Chrome uses webkit, which is more fast and powerfull, while IE(the sad face) uses something different(no one even cares to know about it).

So it may differ but also try that is it happening only on your computer, try running it on a different computer.

Try some CSS driven plugins as CSS rendering is faster as compared to that of javascript.